# Force Resize points Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there a way to programmaticaly focus a image so that the "resize points" get visible and the user can resize the image?

I've already tried `focus()` but that did not work for me.

Here's an example for those "resize-points" .. really.. what are those called anyway?

[image]

Comment: Yes, resize points! Okay!

Comment: As for the resize points (handles), you may need a third-party library

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you meant by *resize points*. But to use the `focus()` on a non-focussable element like `<img />` you need to add `tabindex` attribute to it. Just give `tabindex="1"` to the `<img />` like:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" tabindex="1" />
```

And after that trigger the `focus()` on it.

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("img").trigger("focus");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
img {display: block;}
img:focus {border: 2px solid #f00;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The image receieves focus in a second!</p>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" tabindex="1" />
```